# Configure Google App Engine to serve a JS client side app

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I have a basic `flask` app that uses the `flask_restful` extension (for making restful services):

**main.py**

```
from google.cloud import datastore
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

datastore_client = datastore.Client()

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        # retrieve from datastore here
        return {'greeting': 'hello'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/greet')
```

Typically, a flask app will render a template like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

By default, flask will retrieve `index.html` from the 
 `templates/index.html` directory.

However, when the `/` route is visited, I do not want to render the a template. Instead, I would like to serve a JS client app (Angular, React, Vue) inside an entirely different directory within the app engine project:

```
my-gae-project/
    app.yaml
    main.py
    main_test.py
    requirements.txt
    app/          <--- JS app lives here; consumes flask restful api
        src/
            index.html
            script.js
            style.js
        build/
            index.html
```

At first, I thought it would be as easy as modifying the `app.yaml` file to point to the `app/` subdirectory:

```
runtime: python37

handlers: 

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /app
  static_dir: app

- url: /.*      <--- route all requests to '/' to app.index.html
  script: app/index.html
```

But this does not work. So, how exactly can I serve a JS client within GAE that consumes the flask rest API?

Answer (score 1):

This would not be recommended in production on App Engine, you can either decide whether you would like to develop your whole application in Python Flask or JS (React, Angular, Vue).

The best solution to this, would be to divide your application into [two services.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/communicating-between-services) running on GAE

Comment: does this mean that one service is the pure Python/Flask Rest API and the other service is JS client? If so, I assume that the dispatch.yaml will direct all traffic to the "JS client" service which then consumes the restful api service?

Comment: Yes and Yes.
One Service will be in Python and the other in JavaScript, and once a request is made to /index for example, your [dispatch.yaml][1] will direct traffic to the JS service.

[1]; https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/dispatch-yaml